# iframe cannot get content

Tags: html, iframe

I put this in my webpage:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

The resulting `<iframe>` is blank. Looking at the Google Chrome developer console, I see the error

```
GET http://www.google.com/ undefined (undefined)
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: Google is preventing their site from being embedded in an iframe. I can't remember the acronym for the technology but most big sites do it nowadays

Comment: It's `X-FRAME-OPTIONS`. http://drupal.org/node/1006980